# Local orthonormalization of vector fields

Tags: metric-spaces, control-theory, vector-fields, orthonormal

Consider the  control system 
$$
\dot q = u_1 X(q) + u_2 Y(q) = F(q) U, \qquad q\in \mathbb{R}^3
$$
where $U=(u,v)$ is a  control, and $X,Y$ are vector fields such that 
$X(2)=Y(3)=1$ and $X(3)=Y(2)=0$.

Let $g$ be the (Riemannian) metric
$$
g = a(q) u_1^2+2b(q)u_1u_2 +c(q)u_2^2 = U^TSU
$$
for some (smooth) functions $a,b,c$.

I would like to find a feedback $U = \beta(q)V$
such that the metric $\tilde g$ associated with the new controls $V$ is Euclidean, that
is
$$
\tilde g = v_1^2+v_2^2
$$

The problem is that if I can't find $\beta$ on all the domain so I was thinking to make an expansion in space for $\beta$ and find its coefficients to rectify the metric.

I would like some references about such calculations.

The system that I have to solve is
$$
\beta^T S \beta = Id_2
$$

Shall I write $\beta_{11} = \sum_{i,j,k} \alpha_{i,j,k} q_1^i q_2^j q_3^k$
where $q=(q_1,q_2,q_3)$ and $\beta=(\beta_{ij})$ ? and so on ?
and then find $\alpha_{i,j,k}$ ?

Comment: Can't you write $S$ as $M^\top\,M$, in which case $\beta = M^{-1}$? Or have you tried this, but always got a $M$ which would be singular for some $q$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $S(q)$ is a symmetric matrix. According to [Sylvester's law of inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia), a symmetric matrix can always be transformed by a congruence transformation (=P^TSP) to a diagonal form  with only $1$, $-1$, and $0$'s along the diagonal and the number of respective elements is an invariant of $S$. The conclusion is that you can transform your $S(q)$ to an identity matrix if $S(q)$ has positive eigenvalues for all $q$.